# Razor CheckboxFor and RadioButtonFor in a nested loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nested-loops

Here is my model

```
public class Settings
{
  public string Label { get; set; }
  public bool Display { get; set; } //controls checkbox
  public bool Default { get; set; } //controls radiobutton
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult LaunchSettings(int portletInstanceId)
{
  List<List<Settings>> listOfGroups;
  return PartialView("Settings", listOfGroups);
}
```

Here is my view

```
  @foreach (List<Settings> group in Model)
  {
    foreach(Settings settings in group)
    {
      <ol>
        <li>
          *****ADD CHECKBOX FOR EACH ITEM IN THE LIST*****
        </li>
        <li>
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => settings.Label)
        </li>
        <li>
          *****ADD SET OF RADIO BUTTONS HERE PER GROUP*****
        </li>
      </ol>
    }
  }
```

The inner list contains settings that are grouped based on the group id of the data.  The outer list of a list of the inner list.

How do I achieve each of the tasks described in my view above between the "*****" tags?  I searched on google and couldn't find an appropriate answer.  If I missed something, please understand that it's not due to lack of searching.

EDIT
  Here is the xml that drives the model

```
 <state>
  <searchoptions>
    <searchoption name="Option1" label="Option A" display="true" default="true" group="1"/>
    <searchoption name="Option2" label="Option B" display="true" default="false" group="1"/>
    <searchoption name="Option3" label="Option C" display="false" default="false" group="1"/>
    <searchoption name="Option4" label="Option D" display="false" group="2"/>
    <searchoption name="Option5" label="Option E" display="false" group="3"/>
  </searchoptions>
 </state>
```

Comment: could you describe the problem a bit more... I am not sure I understand your problem... You could simply have a case statement or some if elses and you could place your RadioButtonFor's and CheckBoxFor's inside there